# How to use a modified ls program to execute another program?

Tags: c, linux, terminal, privileges, ls

I got a modified ls:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char command[50];
    strcpy(command,"/bin/ls ");
    gid_t egid = getegid();
    setregid(egid, egid);
    if(argc > 1) {
        if(strlen(argv[1]) > 40) {
            printf("The command you have given is too long, try again.\n");
            return 0;
        }
        strcat(command,argv[1]);
        system(command);
    }else{
        printf("This is a special NSA-modified 'ls' program. See 'man ls' for further details on how to use it.\n");
        printf("USAGE: %s [flags & files]\n",argv[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have to execute a program called get-code but i don't have the privileges to execute it without the ls (the modified ls is in the same directory as the get-code program), so how can I execute the get-code program using the modified ls?

Can someone help me?

Comment: `system()` will execute `command` as if it was typed into a shell. You need to find a way to trick `system()` into running another command after `ls`.

Comment: that is what i already found out but i don't know what extra command @rmartinjak

Comment: "I have to execute a program called get-code"

Comment: already did ./ls -exec /some-maps/get-code {} \; just like i said i dont have other privileges, only ls is the one that can open it with the privileges of the root and i dont know how to execute with ls @rmartinjak

Comment: Is this homework? It looks like an exercise in properly checking your input for special characters (cleaning input), since the result is a security violation. As a hint, you can put the argument in quotes, and then any character you type will be in the argument, even ones that have special meaning to the shell.

Comment: yes the previous course was with a modified find program and i used that to finish the course... i am really new to this and i am 17 thats why i asked for help because the teacher said that that is allowed

Comment: they gave me the modified ls so i can indeed trojan the get-code program to actually open it with the right permissions while i dont have them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad the teacher said it is allowed.  Actually I would have a bigger problem is this was a real-life issue -- what you are trying to do is exploit a security hole, and that's not a good idea in the real world.

This exercise is designed to show you how careful you have to be when writing code so that you don't open big security holes in the system. The "ls" command does not have any option to exec another program. The program adds absolutely anything you have in the arg1 to the end of the string "/bin/ls". If you know shell, you know that the ";" character separates two commands. Can you think of a way to set up the argument so that it has a semi-colon and then the command you want to run?

Comment: no i dont know how because they gave us the courses with only the knowledge of making a website... but yeah the whole course is called Security1 so we learn what the gaps are in security and how to make a pc stronger against hacking... they said: you know why hackers can hack by hacking yourself :/ but yeah not that much knowledge of it

Comment: Well, I would recommend reading some more on the shell, "man bash" is a great place to start. System just runs the string in a shell, so if that string was "/bin/ls ; /some-maps/get-code" it will run ls and then run get-code.

Comment: the first if denies me from doing it

Comment: Ok, you are getting there. You can only have 40 characters in the argument. I notice that you are putting /bin/ls in the argument, and that is not needed. I think it you just use ";./get-code" as the argument it is under 40 characters.

Comment: :D thanks for the amazing help! http://puu.sh/7qJSB.png it did work! i got my special code for excercize 6 i hope it is something else this time!

Comment: No problem. Be sure to vote for the answer and mark it correct!

Comment: how to vote? i have only 6 reputation i joined today :/ i need 15

Comment: Just click the up-triangle above the 0 on the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Hate to grub for points.  I have to go home now, you'll have to post the next exercise as a new question.